# How to load NSViewController on a NSApplicationDelegate

Tags: swift, macos, appdelegate

I'm trying to load a ViewController on my appDelegate class. Like this:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

  var viewController = HomeViewController()

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
     self.window.backgroundColor = NSColor(rgba: "#02303A")
     self.viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.window.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.window.frame))
     self.window.contentView?.addSubview(self.viewController.view)
  }

}
```

My view controller is very simples, just:

```
import PureLayout

class HomeViewController : NSViewController {

  let search : NSSearchField = {
    let search = NSSearchField.newAutoLayoutView()
    return search
  }()

  override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(search)
  }

}
```

But when the I compile the project, the log returns:

[image: Error]

The repository with the complete source code: [Github](https://github.com/ppamorim/Gradle-OSX)

Anyone know what can be? I do this on my iOS projects and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have no xib file belonging to your view controller, so the first step is to add a new file for the **view**:

[image]

2. In your newly created xib file, select the **File's Owner** placeholder, and in the Inspector, set its custom class to your view controller subclass:

[image]

3. Finally, connect the **view** outlet from the view controller *(the File's Owner)* to the Custom View object.

[image]

(Build your user interface for the view controller in this view, rather than the one in your main nib.)